# MongoDB count with query return more records than a count all

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've noticed a strange behaviour of MongoDB and I'm try to guess what can be the problem:

I've a MongoDB with a lot of documents inside a collection. I've run the following query:

```
db.mydocuments.count({_id:{$lte:new ObjectId("549010c9e4b06c2f044f27f4")}});
```

The result is 66.579.389 documents

Than I ran the following:

```
db.mydocuments.count();
```

and surprisingly I've got the following total: 32.606.242

How this can be? how the whole count of a collection can be less than a count with a query?At least it need to be equal to the query count.

The db.mydocument.stats() is:

```
{
"ns" : "mydb.documents.photos",
"count" : 32606242,
"size" : 76109891776,
"avgObjSize" : 2334,
"storageSize" : 164665658240,
"numExtents" : 97,
"nindexes" : 1,
"lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
"paddingFactor" : 1,
"systemFlags" : 0,
"userFlags" : 0,
"totalIndexSize" : 1944138336,
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 1944138336
},
"ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: No, I'm not using sharding (I've also found that could be a problem on orphaned documents, but no it's just a single machine)

Comment: What is the document count from `db.mydocuments.stats()`? Do you have another index you can test the count against?

Comment: I've just edited the question with stats,  and unfortunately I don't have another index to test

Answer (score 0):

.stats() returns you amount of allocated records as well as average object size, extents etc.
This call is not supposed to get exact information about your collection (like a number of documents).

Example:
you inserted 100 docs, then deleted 99. The collection is still allocated to handle 100 docs.
Do not rely on .stats() call unless you need it for informational purposes only.

In your case, we have exact opposite behavior. May be, broken index.